# Multiple join rules in Laravel/Eloquent relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm developing a sports system where `games` table has 2 relations for the same table `teams`. I know the context usuallty doesn't matter, but I'm trying to make it clear why the database is stuctured that way. The relations are stored as `games.home_id references teams.id` and `games.away_id references teams.id` to link the 2 teams in the same game.  The tables structures are

```
- games
  - id
  - home_id
  - away_id
  - starts_at

- teams
  - id

- team_players
  - id
  - team_id
```

So, if I want to get all the players of the games to be played today I'll do

```sql
SELECT team_players.*
FROM team_players
    JOIN teams ON (teams.team_id = team_players.team_id)
    JOIN games ON (teams.id = games.home_id OR teams.id = games.away_id)
WHERE games.starts_at <= $starts AND  games.starts_at >= $ends
```

How do I create the `hasMany` relationships in the models to include both `(team.id = games.home_id OR team.id = games.away_id)`?

I already tried something like

```php
class Team { 
    public function game() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class); 
    }
}

class Game {
    public function teams()
    {
        $rel = $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'home_id'); 
        $rel->orHasMany(Game::class, 'home_id');
        return $rel;
    }
}
```

but there is no `orHasMany()`;

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define two `has-many-through` relationships and merge them, it is not tested, but I think it can be the solution for you, please test it and let me know, also you may need to change a little bit about the keys, I have just written to give you some idea

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public function homeTeamPlayers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\TeamPlayer',
            'App\Team',
            'id', // Foreign key on teams table...
            'team_id', // Foreign key on team_players table...
            'home_id', // Local key on games table...
            'id' // Local key on teams table...
        );
    }

     public function awayTeamPlayers()
     {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\TeamPlayer',
            'App\Team',
            'id', // Foreign key on teams table...
            'team_id', // Foreign key on team_players table...
            'away_id', // Local key on games table...
            'id' // Local key on teams table...
        );
    }

    public function teamPlayers()
    {
        $this->homeTeamPlayers->merge($this->awayTeamPlayers);
    }
}
```

now, for every game you can retrieve like

```
$game = Game::find(1);
$game->teamPlayers();
```